# Custom function that counts blank cells in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I want to write COUNTBLANK1 function to count empty cells with 4 parameters: starting row, starting column, number of rows to count, number of columns to count. For example: COUNTBLANK1(2;3;1000;1). Here are instructions I got from someone:

```
function COUNTBLANK1(startRow, startColumn, numRows, numColumns) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange(startRow, startColumn, numRows, numColumns);
  var values = range.getValues();
  var count = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < numColumns; j++) {
      if (values[i][j] == "") {
        count++;
      }
    }
  }
  return count;
}
```

However it didn't work, when I ran it, Google gave me the following error:

> Exception: The parameters (null,null,null,null) don't match the method
> signature for SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange.

Please let me know how to make it work, many thanks.

Comment: You need to call the function with four values (startRow, startColumn, numRows, numColumns). It sounds like you're just calling it like this `COUNTBLANK_CUSTOM();`

Comment: @Lee Taylor Sorry for my incompetence, but I don't understand what you mean. Can you give me a clearer example? Thanks a lot.

Comment: From `Custom function that counts blank cells in Google Spreadsheet` and your question, in your question, it seems that you are using a function `COUNTBLANK1` like `=COUNTBLANK1(2;3;1000;1)`. But, in your script, the function name is `COUNTBLANK_CUSTOM`. I'm worried that you might have miscopied the function name or your script. If you want to use your showing script for a custom function with the arguments of `2;3;1000;1`, how about putting a custom function `=COUNTBLANK_CUSTOM(2;3;1000;1)` into a cell?

Comment: By the way, please don't directly run the function `COUNTBLANK_CUSTOM` with the script editor because of no arguments. Please be careful about this.

Comment: @Tanaike I found out where I went wrong, I ran this function directly with the script editor. I applied it in the spreadsheet and it works fine. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Tanaike noted in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76346348/custom-function-that-counts-blank-cells-in-google-spreadsheet/76347082#comment134628780_76346348): Don't directly run the function with the script editor because of no arguments. This was the cause of my problem.